# proxy software that supports parallel transfer

Tags: proxy, http, parallels, socks-proxy

I need to setup a really fast proxy server in a remote server, here's the scenario:

1. The server prefetches 3KB of data, mostly HTTP resources.
2. The server send to client 3KB of data, instead of traditional HTTP or SOCKS proxy, the server open multithreaded transfer with 3 connections, send 1KB of data per thread to each connection
3. The client receives 1KBx3, and combine them to the original 3KB data, and return as a local HTTP proxy server.
4. The client display the original data in browser via the local HTTP proxy

The latency is not important as long as the transfer rate is good.

Does any software like this exist? It's better if it's open source or free ones.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the proxy and the client to simultaneously communicate over 3 TCP connections, instead of just one.  Why do you think this will yield higher throughput than a single TCP connection?

Comment: Does this question help? http://superuser.com/questions/505786/splitting-an-http-request-into-multiple-byte-range-requests

Comment: @redpola looking good thanks. But it's for download only, not general purpose browsing acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a list of some proxy servers.

However, I think that the parallel connections are mostly managed in a transparent manner by the proxy server, meaning that it's the client that opens the multiple connections thru the proxy server, which only serves as a gateway.

[WinGate Proxy Server](http://www.qbik.com/products/wingate/index.php)
Commercial software ($74.95 for 3 concurrent users).

[WinProxy](http://www.winproxy.net/) ($99)
Demo version is free for two users.

[Proxy+](http://www.proxyplus.cz/)
Free for 3 users.

**EDIT**

Since the above were not what you are looking for, here are some more:

[SmoothWall Express](http://www.smoothwall.org/)
[Vyatta.org](http://www.vyatta.org/)
[Endian](http://www.endian.com/en/community/feature-comparison/)

Comment: Sorry but these are not the software I wanted

Comment: See more products above.

Comment: Man, those are cooperate firewall solutions. Did you know what I am talking about?

Comment: These are also proxy servers.

Answer (score 0):

The client (a web browser) will never request more than one resource at a time (well, most browsers actually use two independent channels but never request the same resource on both), and won't request partial resources unless instructed to do so. Without a custom web browser, there isn't a proxy server that will do that (at least that I am aware of) as this is really client side behavior. Assuming you had a working client, most proxy servers will support what you desire.

Is there a reason it has to be a remote proxy? You could configure a proxy on your computer or on your LAN to act as a proxy that will prefetch pages and keep a local cache relatively hot, and most of the static resources (like images) will be served locally.