# Splitting an HTTP request into multiple byte-range requests

Tags: proxy, http, multiplexing

I have arrived at the unusual situation of having two completely independent Internet connections to my home. This has the advantage of redundancy etc but the drawback that both connections max out at about 6Mb/s.

So one individual outbound http request is directed by my "intelligent gateway" (TP-LINK ER6120) out over one or the other connection for its lifetime. This works fine over complex web pages and utilises both external connects fine. However, single-http-request downloads are limited to the maximum rate of one of the two connections.

So I'm thinking, surely I can setup some kind of proxy server to direct all my http requests to. For each incoming http request, the proxy server will issue multiple byte-range requests for the desired data and manage the reassembly and delivery of that data to the client's request.

I can see this has some overhead, and also some edge cases where there will be blocking problems waiting for data. I also imagine webmasters of single-servers would rather I didn't hit them with 8 byte-range requests instead of one request.

How can I achieve this http request deconstruct/reconstruction? Or am I just barking mad?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search turns up [axel-proxy](http://sam.nipl.net/axel-proxy/axel-proxy), which apparently does exactly what you are asking for. It is somewhat uncommon to see an HTTP proxy implemented by a shell script, but there you go. :)

Comment: That is pretty near to what I wanted. It looks like the proxy part is fairly primitive, but it's a starting point. Many thanks. Out of curiosity, what did you search for? I had a hard time finding a good search term.

Comment: I'd already used `axel` as a download accelerator a couple of times in the past, so I used `axel` and `proxy` as search terms and was (pleasantly) surprised by the result.