# TCP splicer/splitter (proxy)

Tags: networking, proxy, tcp

There's a big problem with satellite ISP's, that is shaping any TCP-connection to 4 Mbps.
Since alomost any software uses single TCP-connection, resultinhg speed is limited.

I've encountered previously here one [pretty old post](https://superuser.com/questions/85651/proxy-software-that-supports-parallel-transfer?newreg=d7322a2c86ea49cd9bedb6fc387800cb) with similar question about proxy, that's capable of splitting/slicing 1 TCP-connection to many conccurrent connection.

Tried shadowsocks w/ V2Ray-plugin with option of `mux=1` (multiplexing several connections to proxy-server), but it doesn't split client software connection :'(

There is [tcpsplice](https://github.com/pyke369/tcpsplice) out there, but not finished, obviously...
There is such a thing as Performance Enhancing Proxy (PEP) hardware like Xiplink, splitting 1 connection to 2-6 concurrent ones, but it's too pricey.

Any ideas?